# what is the default Garbage-Collection for Java 7

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

I know the default `Garbage-Collection` for **Java 6** is serial/serial-old in client mode.

But I don't know, what is the default `Garbage-Collection` for **Java 7** in client mode.

Anyone can tell me what is the default for Java 7?

Comment: This depends on the JVM and the information can usually be found in the documentation of the particular JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using an OpenJDK based build of JDK 7 you can use the `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` option on the command line. This will tell you what flags have been set by default (as well as any you have explicitly set, but then you know what they are because you set them).